# Multipart File upload using Springfox and Swagger-ui

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, swagger-ui

I'm using Spring MVC as a rest controller and I've integrated Swagger-ui with my controller using Springfox. I'd like to have a method that is able to upload a file via the Swagger-ui interface. I only need two parameters, a long acting for an object id and the file to be uploaded.

```java
@RestController
public class controller{
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam Long id,
                           @RequestParam MultipartFile file){
          //do some stuff
    }
}
```

I've tried almost everything and I can't get a file upload button to appear. However, if I do:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller{
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam Long id,
                           @RequestPart File file){
         //do some stuff
    }
}
```

The file upload button appears, but it always throws http code 415 when trying to upload a file. Besides, I need the input to be a MultipartFile, not a regular File. Even if I use the @RequestPart annotation with Multipart File, the choose file to upload button does not appear. How can I get this to work???? Even:

```java
@RestController
public class Controller{
    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadFile(@RequestPart String metaData,
                           @RequestPart MultipartFile file){
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Won't work. If someone could give a walkthrough of how to get this button to appear for MultipartFile? I'd be forever grateful.

Comment: It would be nice if you set the correct answer.

Answer (score 28):

I think you are missing the *consumes* attribute of the *@RequestMapping* in your second snippet. See the following example

```
@RequestMapping(
    path = "/upload", 
    method = RequestMethod.POST, 
    consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> handleUpload(
        @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, 
        @RequestParam("someId") Long someId,         
        @RequestParam("someOtherId") Long someOtherId) { 
    return new ResponseEntity<>();
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Use

`@RequestPart(required = true) MultipartFile file`

And use the version number 2.1.0 or latest, there is a bug with previous versions.

https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/786

Answer (score 12):

In my situation, there were two things I needed to do

1. My MultipartFile request param had to be named 'file', otherwise, swagger-ui wouldn't display the file upload input control

> ```
> @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
> ```

2. I had to register the following bean

> ```
> @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
> public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver(){
>     return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your code snippet.<br/> I've used the solution from [SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32992815/3122531), but it implied to use XML config for Spring, which I was trying to avoid :)  
  
It should be pointed that, when using Maven/Gradle/etc, you have to add dependency for [Apache Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) library (at least I had to), otherwise Spring IoC system could not retrieve a bean to delegate file upload to.

Comment: in my case, I had to change  @ RequestParam to @ RequestPart like the original answer.maybe you should edit answer. ty

Answer (score 10):

Try using @RequestPart for MultipartFile instead of @RequestParam

```
@RestController
public class controller {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void uploadFile(@RequestParam Long id,
                       @RequestPart MultipartFile file) {
        //do some stuff
    }

}
```

Comment: This does answer does not add anything that hasnt already been provided by previous answers

Answer (score 6):

Two things...

1. Value of consumes should should be `"multipart/form-data"`. `consumes="multipart/form-data"`
2. `@RequestPart("file") @ApiParam(value="File", required=true) MultipartFile file`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

After trying all of above solution, I still have 1 point that can't rendering the Multipart File in Swagger open ai. I found the solution by a little bit change in Controller class:

- Use @ApiParam and @RequestPart.
- Use @RequestMapping instead of @PostMapping.
  I have no idea why @RequestMapping works instead of @PostMapping.
  My workspace's using below dependencies:

> org.springframework.boot
>   spring-boot-starter-web

> org.springdoc
>   springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui
>   2.3.0

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)