# Geting HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present in spring

Tags: java, spring, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file using `spring`. Below is my code how I am working on it
but if I try to use it I am getting this `response`:

HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present

I dont get what the error is.

I am using advanced rest client for testing and I am uploading file as an attachment.

My Javacode:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload",headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
    {
        String name= "test.xlsx";
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name)));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + "!";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your request?

Comment: <html>
<body>
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
  action="http://localhost:8080/upload">
  File to upload: <input type="file" name="file"><br /> <br /> <input type="submit"
   value="Upload"> Press here to upload the file!
 </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Just a try. Add `class="file"` to the input. `<input type="file" class="file" name="file"/>`

Comment: Do you have `<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />` in your context.xml?

Comment: no what is the use of it and where do i need to keep it

Comment: Its for telling Spring to use commons-upload library to handle the file upload form. Should be in your application context file as a bean declaration.

Comment: in dispatcher servlet? in my case

Comment: Show your JSP where you are sending that request and your config where you have declared the bean.

Comment: i havent declared the bean

Comment: Spring needs this bean for file-uploads

Comment: i am getting 415 unsupported media type now

Comment: delete your `headers = "Content-Type=multipart/form-data"` information in your controller and try again.  And maybe delete your `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Comment: it worked if i use enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring needs the

`<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />`

bean to handle file-uploads.

You should register this bean in your `application context` file.

The Content-Type should also be valid. In your case `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

**EDIT1:**

You can give the upload and memory size to the bean properties:

```
  <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

        <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->

    </bean>
```

Comment: cant i change content type to some thing else

Comment: It depends on your content type you or the client want to send and the server receive. I think it should also work with ´application/json`.

Comment: what is the max size of the file to upload

Comment: Don't we need Multipart filter declaration in 'web.xml' file, liek this :   <filter>
    <filter-name>multipartResolver</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>multipartResolver</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

Comment: first it doesn't seem to work, but when i restart the server it worked. thank you :)

Comment: This is the way how to config it as Java bean - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118099/how-to-config-commonsmultipartresolver-in-spring4-without-xml-to-upload-file

Answer (score 2):

when you select the file in advance rest client, on the **right side** there is a **input box**, write in that input box name of the **parameter**, in your case name of parameter is **file**

Parameter name defined here in controller **@RequestParam("file")**

[image]

Comment: yeah i am using in thatb way

Comment: please attach your screenshot

Comment: do you have any bean id using for this case it solved in my case if i use bean id

Answer (score 0):

it works for me after i wrote in that input box name of the parameter "file" when i already have well configured the bean id in the Krajee bootstrap inputfile example ("https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput").