# Unable to upload multiple images in one request using Java and Angular js

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, image-uploading

I am able to upload single image with form data. But now i want to upload multiple images with form data.I have referred many answers but still in server code am getting null for `files`.

In Angular controller, form data appends list of files,But which is empty in Spring controller.
Please help,

**Entity**

```
@Id
@Column(name="productId")
private Integer productId;

@Column(name="itemName", unique = true)
private String itemName;
     
@Column(name="twoDByteArray",columnDefinition="mediumblob")
private byte[][] twoDByteArray=new byte[10][];
```

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Product addProduct(@RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] files, @RequestPart("product") Product product,HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, SerialException, SQLException {

    if(file!=null){
        byte[][] data1 = new byte[10][];  
        byte[] contents = file.getBytes();
        data1[0] = contents;
        product.setTwoDByteArray(data1);
    }
    return product;
}
```

**Controller.js**

```
scope.addProduct = function (product,files) {
    alert(product);
    alert(files);
        scope.files = files;
        if (files && files.length) {
            Upload.upload({
                url: '/Admin_Test/addProduct',
                /*fields: {'username': 'Roja'}, // additional data to send
                files: files*/
                data: {
                    files: files,'product':product
                }
            }).then(function (response) {
                timeout(function () {
                    scope.result = response.data;
                });
            }, function (response) {
                if (response.status > 0) {
                    scope.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
                }
            }, function (evt) {
                scope.progress = 
                    Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
        }
    };
```

**Html**

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="$files" multiple 
 name="file" accept="image/*" ngf-max-size="2MB" required /> 
        <!--  <div class="col-sm-4 form-group ">
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple="true" >
        </div> -->
                        
<input type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"
value="Submit" ng-click="addProduct(product,$files)" />
```

**edit**

After using ng-upload, i can see image details in console,but which are not present in file.

> DEBUG CommonsMultipartResolver:287 - Found multipart file [files[0]] of size 3384 bytes with original filename [hh1.png], stored in memory
>
> DEBUG CommonsMultipartResolver:287 - Found multipart file [files[1]] of size 8591 bytes with original filename [hh.png], stored in memory

Thank you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p7uuy2as/  try this code using ng-file-upload library

Comment: check the https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload you will find it in here

Comment: @zabusa with ng-upload also same issue in server side

Comment: multiple files in one request is not good. You can't handle errors e.g. what do you do, if 1 file is not able to be uploaded? cancel whole request? some files were already uploaded, rollback?
Just do 1 request per file and you are safe.

Comment: @CodeNashor But my requirement is to upload multiple images,lets say with form data of 3 fields, need to submit those images also. And entire object to be saved.Any help..?

Comment: You still can upload the files one by one without users knowledge. Its much more safer, ng-upload has problems with multiple files and crossbrowser especially IE 10+ does some weird things in some situations.

Comment: @CodeNashor So u mean to say on each selection of image.But how to handle java side.?I want to save in single object itself,at one time to database..

Comment: @CodeNashor can you give me a over view of it. So tht i will try to implement it

Comment: Create Database object on the first request and store it in database, all other requests will just update the database entry. 
The problem here: the following requests have to know, that they just update a existing database entry, not creating a new one. Hope you have something like 'id: 1, files: files', then you send the request like 'id 1: file: file1' next request 'id: 1, file: file2'. In Java you create the object on first request, and update it on the following requests with the same id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161580/discussion-between-hema-and-codenashor).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46708678/7256477 try this

Comment: @Raju I need to submit along with form data in same request

Comment: use  FormData  you can add files and data in single Object thats code is also availabel in above example ($scope.submitdata  function)

Answer (score 2):

try this
**frontend**

```
function uploadFiles(files){
        return Upload.upload({
            url : "your_url",
            method : "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": undefined
            },
            file: files,
            arrayKey: ''
        });
}
```

**backend**

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/uploadFiles"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> file){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

**Angular Controller**

```
Upload.upload({
   url: '/Admin_Test/addProduct',
   files: files,
   data: product
})
```

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Product addProduct(@RequestPart("files") MultipartFile[] files, Product product,HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, SerialException, SQLException {
    if(files!=null){
        System.out.println("In multiple img..."+files +"..."+product);
        System.out.println(product +""+ files);//null null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response.. `org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'product' is not present` am getting bad request error

Comment: What you got in `alert(product);`? And Can you post your POJO `Product` class ?

Comment: In alert i am getting product object with proper values. I have added POJO in my question

Comment: Make sure angular's `product` object and your Java POJO `Product` class have same attributes so spring will Jackson Mapper automatically map your object's attribute.

Comment: I am getting this issue only for multiple files upload, for single file upload product will reach to server side controller

Comment: Have you added `<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />` in `application context` refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990908/geting-http-status-400-required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-present

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162076/discussion-between-hrdkisback-and-hema).

Comment: @Hema, Try to `@RequestMapping(value = "/addProduct", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = ("content-type=multipart/*"))` add `headers`.