# How to upload an image using Swagger-UI RestAPI?

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

First time here and I'm super new to Java. I'm trying to write a program that's like an online store where the customers can upload their own pictures to the site as well (to see how the products would look on them but let's not get into that as we won't actually code that). Our teacher wanted us to find an online image hosting site that'll give an URL back and integrate the site to the project. He specifically asked us to do this through Swagger-UI and RestAPI.

Our instructor didn't show us how to do this and told us to research this but I've been looking for hours and either I'm stupid and can't make what I find work or I just can't find what I need.

We're using Spring.io to create the project (so using gradle) and are using these dependencies when creating the project on Spring:
Lombok
Spring Web
Spring Data JPA
Spring Data JDBC

I tried the steps shown here at this link https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/ in my application.yml file but couldn't get it to work. Not sure if I need to write a method or something as well or not. Sorry if this is a basic question, super new to coding and I got the Rona and my brain has basically been mush the past couple of days. Thank you to everybody who takes the time to read through all this!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

We can use OpenApi to enable swagger as long as it's on the class path. That would require adding the dependency to the build.gradle file. The controller methods will be shown on the Swagger UI that can be reached at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

[image: Dependency for OpenApi]

[image: Example of a controller for file/image upload]

[image: Result on Swagger UI page where you can upload a file]

Comment: Thank you so much this works! Is there a way to turn this upload into a JPG/PNG type only instead of enabling all file types to be uploaded?

Comment: I believe you'll have to do this in service logic or directly in the controller method. For example, check if the content type of the file is equal to JPG/PNG then return a successful response or HttpStatus.OK

Answer (score 0):

The following controller can accept only a GIF/JPG/PNG image. The controller will throw an error when the user tries any other file type:

```java
package org.example.web.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Objects;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestPart;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.server.UnsupportedMediaTypeStatusException;

@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/files")
public class FileController {
  @Value("${server.upload.dir}")
  private String uploadDir;

  @PostMapping(name = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
      throws IOException {
    switch (Objects.requireNonNull(file.getContentType())) {
      case MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE:
      case MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE:
      case MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE:
        processImageUpload(file);
        break;
      default:
        log.error("Unsupported filetype: {}", file.getContentType());
        throw new UnsupportedMediaTypeStatusException(
            String.format("Unsupported filetype: %s", file.getContentType()));
    }

    // Send a response code to the client indicating the Spring file upload was successful
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
        String.format("File uploaded successfully: %s", file.getOriginalFilename()));
  }

  // Service method...
  private void processImageUpload(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    File destFile = Paths.get(uploadDir, file.getOriginalFilename()).toFile();
    file.transferTo(destFile);
    log.info("Uploaded: {}", destFile);
  }
}
```

[image: Swagger file upload]

This could also apply to the following question as well:

> [Multipart File upload using Springfox and Swagger-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31420146/multipart-file-upload-using-springfox-and-swagger-ui)